# Retrieve a char from a char array

Tags: objective-c

Does anyone know how to retrieve a char value from a char array:

```
char* alphaChars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < 12; rowIndex++) 
{
    char* text = (char*)alphaChars[0]; //this throws an error

    //CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, 10, 15, text, strlen(text)); //This is where I wanna use it
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want one character, you don't want to assign it to a pointer:

```
char text = alphaChars[0];
```

Then you would call your next function:

```
CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, 10, 15, &text, 1);
```

If you want the whole string, which is sort of what your code looks like it's doing, you don't need to have an intermediate variable at all.

Comment: Just out of interest:  I didn't know you could pick and choose when to use pointers and when not to.  I thought objects need points and types like int don't.

Comment: @TheLearner, you're right that in Objective-C you can't make a concrete instance of an object; only pointers to objects are allowed.  I suggest you try an online C tutorial or something to get a better grasp on working with pointers.